# Square root of a base 10 positive integer, digit by digit

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

It is possible ([Wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation)) to compute the square root of any number in a digit by digit fashion using a simple (I had learned it in primary school) algorithm.

**Challenge:**

- read a positive integer from the user, in base 10, no error check;
- compute the square root of that integer using a digit-by-digit algorithm (either Wikipedia's or any alternative you may devise);
- display the result, in base 10, with 30 digits after the decimal point (the result must be truncated at the last digit displayed).

**Restrictions:**

- no use of builtin or library *mathematical functions*;
- only arithmetic operations on integers (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and module).

**Scores:**

the shortest correct implementation will be the winner.

---

My reference implementation (Python3, 781 bytes) follows:

```
from math import sqrt

num = input('Give me an integer, ')
n = '0'+num if len(num)%2 else num
couples = [int(''.join(digit for digit in tup))
               for tup in zip(*[iter(n)]*2)]

digits = []
n=0
rem = 0
for couple in couples:
    target = rem*100 + couple
    base = n*20
    for i in range(11):
        if (base+i)*i > target: break
    i = i-1
    digits.append(str(i))
    n = 10*n+i
    rem = target-(base+i)*i

digits.append('.')

for dec_digit in range(30):
    target = rem*100 + 0
    base = n*20
    for i in range(11):
        if (base+i)*i > target: break
    i = i-1
    digits.append(str(i))
    n = 10*n+i
    rem = target-(base+i)*i

print('From math.sqrt: sqrt(%s) = %r'%(num, sqrt(int(num))))
print('Digit by digit: sqrt(%s) = %s'%(num, ''.join(digits)))
```

---

Some test runs:

```
boffi@debian:~/.../tmp$ python3 sqrt.py
Give me an integer, 999901
From math.sqrt: sqrt(999901) = 999.9504987748144
Digit by digit: sqrt(999901) = 999.950498774814352559911780286530
boffi@debian:~/.../tmp$ python3 sqrt.py
Give me an integer, 4
From math.sqrt: sqrt(4) = 2.0
Digit by digit: sqrt(4) = 2.000000000000000000000000000000
boffi@debian:~/.../tmp$
```

Comment: [Things to avoid when writing challenges: non-observable program requirements](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/39242), such as requiring that answers use a specific algorithm.

Comment: following @AndersKaseorg comment, and for math languages that could natively support the required precision, maybe the algorithm requirement could simply be replaced by "without using your language native square root function"

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I was not aware of that restriction, my fault. My question is all about the use of a specific algorithm, what do you suggest me to do? maybe the simplest thing that I can do is to retract my question…

Comment: You could make the algorithm observable by requiring that each step must be output.

Comment: @xigoi I was thinking on that line, but what if I compute at once using builtins and later output the string representation of the result incrementally?

Comment: @gboffi it's not so much a restriction but rather something to be avoided for practical reasons, for example if my language uses your algorithm for the `sqrt` function, simply calling this function would fit your requirements as an answer.. that's why it's preferable to rely on things one can observe. Also for golfing, it can be more interesting to let algorithms open as it can lead to surprising answers

Comment: You can do this by making it a series of both the partial \$sqrt(a)\$ and the remainder as a pair. Challenge to output the \$n^{th}\$ pair (or series up to that pair, or infinitely many) for a given input \$(a,n)\$. Answers may use another algo, but you can't control things to that extent anyway on this site. You may just be pleasantly surprised by some *different* approach.

Comment: @Kaddath I have edited the question to avoid the eventuality you've prospected.

Comment: I think it is not compulsory to require us to output ```Give me an integer, ```. Can you clarify that?

Comment: @Noodle9 I'm a little bit confused by your proposal, is it connected with [xigoi's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/214568/square-root-of-a-base-10-positive-integer-digit-by-digit#comment502064_214568)?

Comment: @SunnyMoon The reference implementation is, ehm, a reference to check  your results, the only requirement is to read the number from the user.

Comment: In languages with a built-in power operator, `float(x)^0.5` doesn't seem to violate any rules? It's not a built-in function, and it's not a non-arithmetic operation on an integer.

Comment: @user253751 ① a float has ~16 decimal digit — yes, you can use something alike Python's `Decimal` but… ② is this digit-by-digit?

Comment: I've VTCed this as unclear as you don't define the algorithm anywhere in the challenge.

Comment: @Shaggy  English not my 1st language, what do you mean with  "_VTCed_"?

Comment: @Shaggy Further, what is unclear in the reference implementation I had provided?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This challenge currently has several places where it is not up to our standards of clarity.  It is not clear what algorithms are permitted (we know at least one but are allowed to devise our own with no clear rules), nor really what it means for a particular algorithm to be used.  Additionally phrases like "no use of builtin or library mathematical functions;" also need a great deal more explanation.  For example what counts as "mathematical" or even more broadly a "function".  These may seem like nitpicks but for codegolf it is essential to have a tight specification.

Comment: I'm going to temporarily close this challenge until clarifications are made.  This will simply stop the flow of new answers.  It can be undone by a moderator or other users once things have been cleared up.  If you have any specific questions feel free to ask me.  I can mostly answer questions although I won't always be able to give advice.

Comment: @WheatWizard My question: this site is not for me, is it possible to unsuscribe it completely?

Comment: @WheatWizard Another question: after the closing, will I be able to accept the perfectly fine answer I've received despite the shortcomings in my question?

Comment: @gboffi You can delete your account somehow, I don't know off the top of my head since I've never done it before.  I don't know if you can accept an answer to a closed question. If the check icon is there you could try, no one can stop you but the software.  I'm not sure why you would want to do that, and I generally advise against accepting answers.  But if you are planning on abandoning this question I don't think it matters very much.  Have a nice one.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 156 bytes

Uses the algorithm suggested by OP, since this is a golf of the reference implementation.

```python
K=input()
n=len(K)%2*'0'+K+'0'*60
R=N=0
while n:
 a,b,*n=n;R=R*100+int(a+b);i=0;N*=20
 while~i*~N<=R:i+=1;N+=1
 print(i,end='.'[len(n)^60:]);R-=N*i;N=N+i>>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BCoMwEADveUUuJSaxZWNB0HT9gJBDrqUFpYILspViKb349VQ7hzkNzPxdxiefU2qReH4vmRaM08BZqw@FUaBsazebEkTEgCA@I02D5FrILu9zw8g@YjQOwBIvWWd77QnBB4MFCPnPVzJruGCsyaLzYZOQ82vPKR/4geqkrvuT9b2E@qZ9PGIw5AMGS03jUqo2wP0A)

Comment: I do not think that it's a golf of a reference implementation, one can use whatever algorithm under the restrictions specified in the question. That said, +1

Comment: @gboffi I guess my formulation was unclear. I meant that my specific answer is a golf of your reference implementation, not the challenge as a whole. All good ;)